# tcolorbox's newtcbtheorem strange numbering by using of several newtcbtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox, newtheorem

I am new with tcolorbox's newtcbtheorem. I get it work to define an own theorem block based on newtcbtheorem but if I use several tcbtheorems the numbering is strange.

I paste a working example where, as you can see below, the numbering works within the chapter but there is twice the number *1.1*

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Korollar}{Korollar}{}{Kor}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A TCOLORBOX TEST}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Korollar}{}{}
  We want to solve $2 + x = 4$.
\end{Korollar}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour is to use a new counter for each kind of theorem. If you don't like that, you can tell the theorem to use the counter from another one by using `use counter from=Theorem`

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Theorem}{Theorem}{}{Th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=Theorem, number within=chapter]{Korollar}{Korollar}{}{Kor}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A TCOLORBOX TEST}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{Korollar}{}{}
  We want to solve $2 + x = 4$.
\end{Korollar}

\begin{Theorem}{}{}
  We have $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]